# Remove duplicate and count from comma separated field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(room_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(room_id, ',', '')) + 1) as total 
  FROM booking
```

I have applied this MySQL query, it working fine but it counts duplicate values. How I can remove duplicate values while count from the comma-separated fields in MySQL.
My Column Like

| id | room_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 4, 5 |
| 2 | 4, 3 |

I want to show the count result total = 4

Now it counts 5

Comment: But there is 5 distinct values in your example: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The example says "sum" and the question says "count". Do you need to count them or to get a sum of all distinct values?

Comment: The best approach is to simply abandon your current table design and stop storing CSV values in this way.  Instead, each `id - room_id` pairing should appear on a separate row.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why does the column `room_id` contain anything else than a number?

Comment: Dear @ekochergin I need a count value, my column value has comma-separated, so I have applied SUM to count comma-separated values. If you have any better process to count comma-separated values from MySQL, please share me.

Comment: `SELECT *, (CHAR_LENGTH(room_id) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(room_id, ',', '')) + 1) as total FROM booking`
 Try this

Comment: @SamirJana now I got it, The first col contains id which is not part of room_id, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As it mention by Tim Biegelstein, the best way is to change database design and never use comma-separated lines that might needed to be splitted.

But I understand this is not always possible, so here is solution I have.

Unfortunately it is applicable to the mysql v8 or newer only. In the 8th version they have added the recursive CTEs which are being used here

```
with recursive booking_splitted(id, room_id, room_parsed, step, steps_needed) as (
  select id,
         substring(room_id, instr(room_id, ',') + 1),
         substring_index(room_id, ',', 1),
         1,
         char_length(room_id) - char_length(replace(room_id, ',', ''))
    from booking
  union all
  select id, 
         substring(room_id, instr(room_id, ',') + 1),
         ifnull(substring_index(room_id, ',', 1), room_id),
         step + 1,
         steps_needed
    from booking_splitted
   where step <= steps_needed
)

select count(distinct room_parsed) rooms
  from booking_splitted
 order by id;
```

The CTE (the part "with recursive ...") splits comma-separated line into rows. So, the line with

| room_id |
| --- |
| 2,4,5 |

will be splitted in 3 records:

| room_id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

And the past part ("select count(distinct ...") counts distinct rooms

UPD. see the [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s7ELWXBCGpb55YxAo41QVH/0) for example